# how do i make it use the id using discord.py

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

i am using the following code to vouch for somebody

```py
@client.command()
async def vouch(ctx,member : discord.Member):
    allowed_channels = [{get_vouch_channel}]
    # Check channels FIRST
    if ctx.channel.id not in allowed_channels:
        return await ctx.send("You can't vouch in this channel")
    
    if ctx.author == member:
      await ctx.send("You can't vouch yourself")
    
    else:

      auth = ctx.author and ctx.author.mention and ctx.author.id
      await open_vouches(ctx.author)
      await open_vouches(member)
      await update_vouches(member,+1,'vouches_gotten')
      await update_vouches(ctx.author,+1,'vouches_given')      
      await ctx.reply(f'<:white_check_mark:827639277285408829> {ctx.author.mention} You vouched for {member}!')
      print('[LOGS] {member} was vouched')
```

i have defined `get_vouch_channel` with the following:

```py
def get_vouch_channel(client, message):
  with open('channel.json', 'r') as f:
    channel = json.load(f)
    return channel[str(message.guild.id)]
```

but for some reason i can't use the `vouch` command in the specified channel. does anybody know how i could fix this?

Comment: What is in channel.json?

Comment: I think you have to call the `get_vouch_channel` with `get_vouch_channel(client, message)` and not with `[{get_vouch_channel}]` as this would be a variable?

Comment: @CaptAngryEyes it puts the server id then the channel

Comment: @FlexGames what would i call it then?

Comment: it works if i just put the id in `[]`

Comment: No I don't mean the name, I mean how to execute it